# How do I get my suggest to only suggest one taxonomy?

Tags: jquery, tags, sql

I am using the built-in wordpress suggest plugin to call the entries from the terms table. 
Using the following sql query it spits out all terms:

```
    $query = 'SELECT term_id,name FROM ' . $wpdb->terms . '
    WHERE name LIKE \'' . $search . '%\'
    ORDER BY name ASC';
```

I would like the restrict the terms that it spits out to one taxonomy, for instance either 'categories' or 'post_tags'. I have tried the sql code below but it comes back with no results.

```
function test() {
global $wpdb;

$search = esc_sql( $wpdb -> esc_like($_REQUEST['q']));

$query = 'Select term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, name FROM ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . '
    JOIN ' . $wpdb->terms . ' ON term_taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id
    WHERE taxonomy = \'catagory\'
    AND name LIKE \'' . $search . '%\'
    ORDER BY name ASC';

foreach ($wpdb->get_results($query) as $row) {
    $name = $row->name;
    $id = $row-> term_id;
   echo $name, "\n";
}
die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'test');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'test');
```

Comment: Then what is the output ?

Comment: You've typoed 'category' as 'catagory' in the SQL, in case that's it?

Comment: This request has no response data available. I have corrected the typo and still no response

Comment: What is the "built-in wordpress suggest plugin"? There is no such thing – unless you are naming something like that what is named otherwise originally. Please clarify (and maybe add a screenshot).

Comment: It is part of the core is sits in \wp-includes\js\jquery\suggest.js. You enqueue it in your functions.php file. `wp_enqueue_script('suggest');` the tags ui in tha admin section uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After join `term_id` exist two times. You should specify which `term_id` you are querying by prefixing full table name (or alias).

Also there is a  other error `term_taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id` missing table prefix.

So the updated query will look like

```
$query = 'SELECT term_taxonomy_id, ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'terms.term_id, taxonomy, name FROM ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . '
    JOIN ' . $wpdb->terms . ' ON ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'term_taxonomy.term_id = ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'terms.term_id
    WHERE taxonomy = \'category\'
    AND name LIKE \'' . $search . '%\'
    ORDER BY name ASC';
```